# How do gallery controls respond to losing internet connection?

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, sharepoint-list

Suppose that I have a Power App open and I have just clicked a page with a gallery that pulls many items from a SharePoint List. After a fraction of a second, I disconnect my internet, wait a minute, and then reconnect it. What will happen to the items in the gallery? Will Power Apps only show me a fraction of the data? Or will the gallery completely fail to load?

[Microsoft gives documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/execution-phases-data-flow) for how data loading works, but I'm not technical enough to read it.

Comment: Usaully, it retries and show all data as it shows while it has internet.

Comment: @Malavan Source?